# Update the data for ggplot2 line graph using the loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, ping

Hi I'm new to programming, and 'R'. Wrote the following code to test my ping continuity:

```
library(pingr)
library(ggplot2)

cc=2
counts <- c(1:1)
pings <- c(ping("8.8.8.8",count = 1))

rgh <- data.frame(counts,pings)
ggplot(rgh, aes(x=counts,y=pings))+geom_line(aes(col="red"))+coord_cartesian(xlim=(c(0,300)),ylim=(c(0,100)))
#qplot(x=counts,y=pings,data=rgh)

while (cc<300) {
  counts <- c(counts,cc)
  pings <- c(pings,ping("8.8.8.8",count = 1))

  rgh <- data.frame(counts,pings)
    print(ggplot(rgh, aes(x=counts,y=pings))+geom_line(aes(col="red"))+coord_cartesian(xlim=(c(0,300)),ylim=(c(0,100))))
    cc <- cc+1

}
```

I wanted to make it look like the cool graph at speedtest.net. But this one redraws the whole plot everytime it loops and that takes too much time. Is there any other way?

Comment: Hmmm, I think ggplot2 method is probably not the best or even "correct" tool/method. You should look into `shiny`.  ggplot2 was design for beautiful static graphs, but shiny was created for dynamic display of data/graphs.

Comment: Will try that :)
Thanks

Comment: @Amar You still need a package for plotting within shiny.

Comment: If isn't too much trouble.. could you please share a sample code in shiny to achieve this result? So I'll know if that is what I'm looking for before I go read tutorials on shiny
.. please ignore if it's not very easy to make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to setup the desired behavior with shiny and plotly:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(pingr)
```

a simple ui with start button  and plot area:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(actionButton("button", "start")),
  div(plotlyOutput("plot"), id='graph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  p <- plot_ly(
    y = ping("8.8.8.8",count = 1),
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines') 
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(p)
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    while(TRUE){
      Sys.sleep(1)
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(ping("8.8.8.8",count = 1)))), list(0))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

after some time it looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: answer to the question in comment:
There are various ways to control the number of pings. Perhaps the simplest:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  p <- plot_ly(
    y = ping("8.8.8.8",count = 1),
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines') 
  a = 1
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(p)
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    while(a <= 30){
      a <- a + 1
      Sys.sleep(1)
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(ping("8.8.8.8",count = 1)))), list(0))
    }
  })
}
```

Here 30 pings are performed

To change the frequency of pings change `Sys.sleep(1)` to your linking.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try that one

Comment: Hey I'm getting this error; kindly advice.

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6004
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
Warning in origRenderFunc() :
  Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "231439807955"; Shiny doesn't use them

Comment: nevermind, it's working fine on 'run on window' :) Thanks!
But where on the code do we mention the number of pings to be conducted?

Comment: Updated answer. Check please.

Comment: Thanks @missuse :)

Comment: Glad if I could be of help. If my answer solved your problem [consider marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).